# Why I cannot achive to desired speedup in parallelised memory bound application in java?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

My application is memory bound. I employed producer-consumer algorithm. Producer generates lots of big objects (more than 60 GIGs for 20 millions of input dataset record) and consumer fetch them from a shared queue.
When I scale up my input dataset the speed up drops dramatically. I monitored GC but it seems that it does not interrupt the application. I cannot achieve speedup more than 6 using 16 threads. I am using following hotspot parameters for running my application and using jdk 1.8. Please help me!

1. -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
2. -d64
3. -Xms200G -Xmx200G
4. -verbose:gc
5. -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
6. -XX:+PrintGCDetails
7. -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
8. -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
9. -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
10. -XX:ParallelCMSThreads=2
11. -XX:NewRatio=1
12. -XX:-UseBiasedLocking
13. -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics
14. -XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1

Comment: The best speedup depend on the code, some jvm arguments may speed up code 1, some arguments decrease the speed for the same code

Comment: Without infos on your code and your machine there's no way we can tell what happens there.

Comment: @Ferrybig Could you please tell me which arguments might decrease speedup and under what circumstances?

Comment: @StepTNT: I have a tree and each node has data structure like p(x,y,z). Then producer will spawn each node to thousands of node based on the size of input dataset (i.e., p(a1,b1,c1), p(a2,b2,c2), . . . . .) and put them into a shares queue. Then producer fetch them and do other instruction on them.

Comment: How many L3 caches and numa regions do you have. If it is 1, 2 or 4, that is the extent of your scalability in terms of memory bandwidth.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Thanks for ur reply. I am using Intel® Xeon® Processor E5620 (240 GHZ) CPU. cashes are L1: 32K, L2: 256K and L3: 12288K. I have 2 numa nodes. how numa can affect the scalability?

Comment: @nasim if you run a JVM in each Numa region, you can get up to 2x scalability. Note this means assigning the JVM to each region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a GC tuning problem, you have to tune your application to keep a very small working set, and if that is not an option, you will not be able to use all your cores at once because your bottleneck is not your CPU power.

Assuming you have a one socket filled in a machine with 16 cores...

You have 16 L1 data caches of 32 KB.  When you access these you get linear scalability. The more cores you use the better. Ideally you want to stay in your L1 cache as much as possible to get full speed.

You have 16 L2 caches of 256 KB.  Again access is scalable, but around 3 x slower.

You have *one* L3 cache of perhaps 40 MB.  Access is slightly concurrent, but in general it is hard to get 2x scalability and it is 10 - 20x slower than your L1 cache.

Basically, unless you stay in your L2 cache, scalability is going to be a problem.  In fact because L3 is much slower as well as shared, you only need 1/160th of your accesses (16 * 10x slower) to hit L3 cache for your average memory access to drop from ~ 1 ns to ~2 ns. That is just 0.6% of all random accesses in a language where you have only indirect control of your memory accesses.

Obviously if you have hyperthreading, your L3 cache is even more contended.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer and time! Now the problem is much more clear to me. Previously I thought that the problem comes from memory limitation or GC and thought that if I use "out of heap memories" it works. My application is not CPU intensive. The only operator in my application is "comparison" and my main algorithm is backtracking algorithm with a polynomial big(O). So it seems to me that even if I reduce the size of sets of data again cannot achieve desirable CPU utilization. Do you think my problem is not essentially parallelizable?

Comment: @nasim The important thing is to identifiy the bottleneck, and most likely your bottleneck is memory access.

Comment: Yes, I think memory is the bottleneck. So do you have any suggestion or solution for this type of program?

Comment: @nasim you need to design your application thinking about how you can minimize memory access. This can mean using smaller data types but more importantly think about the number of random accesses you application performs. This assumes you have minimized the allocation rate, reducing the allocation rate means you spend less time filling the CPU caches with garbage improving their efficiency.

Comment: I am revising my codes carefully based on ur advice. Hope can improve speedup. Thanks for ur advice. Cheers

Comment: @nasim I have found that sometime you change something and it makes little difference and other times it make far more difference than you might expect.  The simplest way to improve this is to look at your allocations in a memory profiler e.g. flight recorder (built in to the JDK) If it don't improve scalability it might just make your program faster. ;)

Comment: I really appreciate! I was looking for something like flight recorder! previously I was using visualVM to monitor my application but it was not informative enough. This is really great!